# SharePoint 2013: Search question -> Searching document title and version!

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-library

I have a document library with versioning and metadata enabled. Our documents go through different "Phases", which we have added as a column/custom content type for metadata filtering.

What the client really had in mind was searching for a document, from the document center, like this

Ex. search query:

"Document Name Phase 3"

***essentially searching through document history, for a specific document in a previous phase, using the Search Center***

Is this possible out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.  Only the last version is surfaced for the search crawler.

You could add a workflow that copied metadata to another list that tracked phases and you could make this searchable.  If you need a direct link to the versioned document that get's messy.  You would need to duplicate the document and keep them all as normal documents in another library - again Search would then pick this up and present them.